# BeagleBoneBlack with debian. IP cannot be set to static

Tags: networking, debian, ip-address, beagleboneblack

I've set up my BeagleBoneBlack with Debian Jessi. As default config it worked with a dhcp ip: 192.168.1.105

But I need to configure the system to use a static ip. Therefore I did in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.50
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

But after a reboot, still the old IP 192.168.1.105 is set. If I do

```
/etc/init.d/networking
```

the new IP is set. But after another reboot, the old one is back again.

Which setting will I have to change to?

I'm not using an additional SD card; Just the eMMC.

Thank you!
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. 
An Intel Connection Manager was installed by default. I overwrites my definition. 
After removing it, it works fine:

```
apt-get purge connman
```